# PM2 is starting my app in fork mode instead of cluster mode

Tags: express, pm2

I'm starting my PM2 (v 3.2.1) app like so:

```
pm2 start server.js --name app -i max --log-date-format 'LLLL'
```

The problem is that this is starting two PM2 processes, but one is constantly getting the `EADDRINUSE` error.

My `server.js` script is as follows:

```
const server = require('./build/bundle.server.js')

server.listen(8081, function () {
  console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${server.address().port}`)
})
```

I've tried deleting all PM2 apps prior to running `pm2 start` with `pm2 stop all` and `pm2 delete all` but the processes still start in fork mode instead of cluster mode.

How can I get my PM2 processes to use cluster mode?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug in PM2 v 3.2.1](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3943) - upgrading to the latest version solved the issue.